# Using dot notation to grab innerHTML or textContent

Tags: javascript, html

This question stems from one I posted recently but is a different "child" question if you will.

I'm learning and fiddling around using the inspect element feature in Chrome's console.

Here is some html on the site in question:

```
<!-- start report description -->
<div class="report-description-text">
<h5>Description</h5>
Welcome to Ushahidi. Please replace this report with a valid incident
<br/>
```

I want to grab the text starting "Welcome to ushahidi..."

I typed this into the console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')
```

And it returned the html of the div in question.

I then tried typing:
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text').h5

But that returned "undefined". I had expected it to return something similar to the above except to show the html for the h5 element, not the parent div.

I wanted to then try:
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text').h5.[text or some other code to grab the inner text]

But I must have misunderstood my textbook on navigating the DOM using dot notation.

The page in question is here: http://tinyurl.com/qxvm5y7

How would I navigate the DOM in this way? What if I wanted to grab other elements? Why am I seeing "undefined"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a DOM [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is *like* an array, so you need to access the index like so:

```
// get the first element with the class name
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0];
```

Your `<h5>` will not be present in the HTMLCollection because it doesn't have the class name. However, you could access it like this:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0];
console.log( div.children[0] ); // get the first child

// or get the first h5
console.log( div.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0] );
```

Comment: Thank you, I never knew it returned an array. Accepting shortly

Comment: No problem :) remember it returns a NodeList object, which isn't the same as an array but is similar in that you can iterate it and access using the index.

Comment: Hold up! I'm almost there but seem to having trouble since the actual text I'm seeking is not wrapped in any tag. The closest I could get was this:
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0].children[0].innerHTML
Which returned "Description".
But I kind of need the adjacent (Sibling) element - though the text is not even in an element. See code in the question above. Is there a way to grab that? I feel like I'm close

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')` returns an array like object, you might want
`document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is invalid because `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like-object. When you try `.h5`, JavaScript looks for a property of the array-like-object called h5. Also, `.h5` won't work even if you select the first element of the array-like-object. You need to use `getElementsByTagName()` to get the `h5`.  You can try to do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0].getElementsByTagName('h5')[0];
```